# Python Tkinter run command after runtime

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I have a class which creates a list of buttons from a queue which is displayed after the customer presses a button.

However, i have a command which is meant to delete an item from a queue when pressed but the content of the command arent running or visually deleting the item from the queue. This command is orderFulfilled(). Is there a way to run the function using the button when pressed?

```
class MyFirstGUI:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    master.title("A simple GUI")

    #self.baristaServed = StringVar()


    self.completedButton = Button(master,text="Complete",width=30,height=5,bg="green", command = MyFirstGUI.orderFulfilled)
    self.completedButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)



    self.barista1 = Button(master,text="Barista 1: Daniel",width=30,height=5)
    self.barista1.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    self.barista2 = Button(master,text="Barista 2: Josh",width=30,height=5)
    self.barista2.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    self.items = []


    for item in selfService.queue1.queue:
        self.button = Button(master,text=item,bg="red", width=35)
        #self.button.bind('<Button-1>', self.baristaServedWhat)
        self.button.pack(side=TOP)
        self.items.append(self.button)


    def orderFulfilled(self):
        print('01')
        selfService.queue1.dequeue()
        self.button = self.items.pop(-1)
        self.button.pack_forget()
        print(selfService.queue1.queue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to call a function with a tkinter button is as follows

```
   myButton = Button(master, text="Press Me", command=myFunction)
```

Where myFunction is the name of the function you wish to be called.

Comment: Ok. When i do it like that, which i have now edited above, I am faced with the error TypeError: orderFulfilled() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Change `command = MyFirstGUI.orderFulfilled` to `self.orderFulfilled`. You are calling the class instance of the method.